# "Copied" columns between tables linked by a foreign key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I essentially want to have some columns automatically copied from one table (here `Director`) to another table (`Movie`) linked by one primary foreign key (here `director_id`).

I am thinking of using `observers` (https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/observers.html#simple-observers): I would copy the required columns each time the foreign key is updated, but the documentation mentions that this "could be done much more efficiently using a compound foreign key", and I can't find how this would be done.

The end purpose is to set a `UniqueConstraint` on the `Movie` table, which uses the `director_name` and `director_date_of_birth` columns. I am all ears if there is a different solution.

```
class Director(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'director'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    date_of_birth = sa.Column(sa.Date)

class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'
    __table_args__ = (
       UniqueConstraint(
          'name', 'director_name', 'director_date_of_birth'
       )
    )
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    director_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey(Director.id))
    director_name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    director_date_of_birth = sa.Column(sa.Date)
    director = sa.orm.relationship(Director, backref='movies')
```

Comment: `UniqueUniqueConstraint(
          'name', 'director_name', 'director_date_of_birth'` It seems to me that director_dob is functionally dependent on director(_id). But I don't really understand this ORM-stuff.

Comment: I realised these placeholder column names are misleading, you could technically have two `Director` rows with the same `name`: `name` and `date_of_birth` are not primary keys (or unique across rows).